# How to debug default frame and depth buffers?

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics

I'm trying to implement shadows on my custom renderer through dynamic shadow mapping and forward rendering (deferred rendering will be implemented later). For instance, everything renders correctly to the Framebuffer used to generate the shadow map. However, when using the default Framebuffer to render the scene normally only the skybox gets rendered (it means that the default Framebuffer is used) and my only hypothesis is that the problem is related with the depth buffer since disabling the call to DrawActors(...) (in ForwardRenderShadows) appears to solve the problem but I can't generate my depth map if doing so. Any suggestions on the matter?

Code:

```
void Scene::DrawActors(const graphics::Shader& shader)
{
    for(const auto& actor : actors_)
         actor->Draw(shader);
}

template <typename T>
void ForwardRenderShadows(const graphics::Shader& shadow_shader, const std::vector<T>& lights)
{   
    for(const auto& light : lights)
    {
          if(light->Shadow())
          {
               light->DrawShadows(shadow_shader); 
               DrawActors(shadow_shader); //removing this line "solves the problem"
               glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
          }
     } 
}

/* 
    shadow mapping is only implemented on directional lights for the moment, and that is the 
    relevant code that gets called when the process starts, more code details at the end of code
    snippet.
*/

void DirectionalLight::SetupShadows()
{
     glGenFramebuffers(1, &framebuffer_);
     glGenTextures(1, &shadow_map_);

     glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, shadow_map_);
     glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, constants::SHADOW_WIDTH, constants::SHADOW_HEIGHT, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, NULL);
     glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
     glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
     glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
     glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);

     glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer_);
     glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_TEXTURE_2D, shadow_map_, 0);
     glDrawBuffer(GL_NONE);
     glReadBuffer(GL_NONE);

     if(glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
          throw std::runtime_error("Directional light framebuffer is not complete \n");

     glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);

     ShadowSetup(true);
}


void DirectionalLight::DrawShadows(const graphics::Shader& shader)
{   
     if(!ShadowSetup())
          SetupShadows();

     glViewport(0, 0,  constants::SHADOW_WIDTH, constants::SHADOW_HEIGHT);
     glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer_);
     glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

     shader.Use();

     projection_ = clutch::Orthopraphic(-10.0f, 10.0f, -10.0f, 10.0f, 1.0f, 100.0f);
     transform_  = clutch::LookAt(direction_ * -1.0f, {0.0f, 0.0f,  0.0f, 0.0f}, {0.0f, 1.0f,  0.0f, 0.0f}); 

     shader.SetUniformMat4("light_transform", projection_ * transform_);
}

void DirectionalLight::Draw(const graphics::Shader& shader)
{
    shader.SetUniform4f("light_dir",   direction_);
    shader.SetUniform4f("light_color", color_);
    shader.SetUniformMat4("light_transform",  transform_);
    shader.SetUniformMat4("light_projection", projection_);
    shader.SetUniformInt("cast_shadow", shadows_);

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE12);
    shader.SetUniformInt("shadow_map", 12);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, shadow_map_);
}
```

Code the repo: https://github.com/rxwp5657/Nitro

Relevant Files for the problem:

- include/core/scene.hpp
- include/core/directional_light.hpp
- include/core/light_shadow.hpp
- include/core/directional_light.hpp
- include/graphics/mesh.hpp
- src/core/scene.cpp
- src/core/directional_light.cpp
- src/core/light_shadow.cpp
- src/core/directional_light.cpp
- src/graphics/mesh.cpp

Finally, what I have tried so far is:

- Deactivating depth testing with glDepthMask(GL_FALSE) and glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST) //same problem.
- Changing depth function to glDepthFunc(GL_ALWAYS); // No desired results;

[image: Example of the error]

Comment: OpenGL debugging is tedious. Mostly, I tried to solve my issues by code staring (and it somehow worked mostly) but this is really ... tedious. With [google "opengl debugger"](https://www.google.com/search?q=opengl+debugger), I found this: [Debugging Tools on khronos.org](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Debugging_Tools), [Learn OpenGL - Debugging](https://learnopengl.com/In-Practice/Debugging). I remember that a colleague once supported me with a tool where all GL state changes appeared visually in a tool (but, unfortunately, I forgot what he used for this).

Comment: Hi Scheff, thanks for your comment. Yeah, OpenGL debugging is really tedious and most issues I've encountered so far are because of incorrect buffer layouts and even on those cases you know that the problem might be just there or even generate some color output to debug shaders but in this case I can't even do that. For instance, my development environment is on MacOS but it seems that I've to change to windows a little bit to get the best out of the tools, I'll comment again whenever I  have any progress. Thanks ;).

Comment: I asked my colleague. He told me the tool was [**apitrace**](https://github.com/apitrace/apitrace). In its doc. it claims to have OS/X support as well.

Comment: Scheff, I just found the error thanks to your tool, apitrace really works. So, the problem is that my vertex data is getting erased or something, this is, normally a vertex is formed by  a position, normal, tangent, texture coords, etc., but when using frame buffers that data gets "overwritten" and now the buffer only has normals. However, that is not the weirdest thing of all, normal vertex data gets overwritten by position data and the other attributes (tangent, true normal, etc) disappears. I'll have to review what is going on since this only happens with frame buffers. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a NVIDIA graphics card, you could have a look a [Nsight](https://developer.nvidia.com/nsight-graphics). You can capture a frame and view all occurred GL-calls.
[image]

Then, you can select an event, for instance the event 22 in my example, and inspect all textures, the color buffer, the depth buffer and the stencil buffer.

[image]

Furthermore, you can have a look on all GL-state parameters at one event.

[image]

Comment: Hi DasElias!, thanks for your answer. Currently, I'm working on my Mac since it has my development environment and yes, I have and NVIDIA graphics card on my rig but it's currently running windows so I have to build the project there in order to use the tool. Also, this tool looks amazing, I'll comment the results of the debugging once there are available. Thanks ;).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after using apitrace I found out that the VBO changes when switching from a custom Framebuffer to the default one. Because of this, the solution to the problem is to set again the VBO after switching to the default frame buffer.

Based on the code of the project, the solution is calling the Setup function again after switching to the default Framebuffer.

Setup function of the Mesh class:

```
void Mesh::Setup(const Shader& shader)
{
     glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao_);
     glBindVertexArray(vao_);

     glGenBuffers(1, &elementbuffer_);
     glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, elementbuffer_);  
     glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indices_.size() * sizeof(unsigned int), &indices_[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

     glGenBuffers(1, &vbo_);
     glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo_);
     glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices_.size() * sizeof(Vertex), &vertices_[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

     shader.PosAttrib("aPosition", 3, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(Vertex),  0);
     shader.PosAttrib("aNormal",   3, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(Vertex),  offsetof(Vertex, normal));
     shader.PosAttrib("aTexCoord", 2, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(Vertex),  offsetof(Vertex, tex_coord));
     shader.PosAttrib("aTangent",  3, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(Vertex),  offsetof(Vertex, tangent));
     shader.PosAttrib("aBitangent",3, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(Vertex),  offsetof(Vertex, bitangent));

     glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
     glBindVertexArray(0);
     loaded_ = true;
}
```

[Vertices buffer after switching to default frame buffer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjuAn.png)

[Vertices buffer with no Framebuffer switching (no shadow map generated)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Raqg.png)